# Деплой телеграм бота с вебхуками

Tags: python, telegram-bot, хостинг, развертывание, webhook

Написал телеграм бота на вебхуках, использовал библиотеку aiogram версии 3.0.0rc2. Во время написания бота пользовался ngrok, для создания базового url`а и написал приложение на aiohttp.

```
async def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{BASE_WEBHOOK_URL}{WEBHOOK_PATH}")


def main():
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
    dp = Dispatcher()

    dp.startup.register(on_startup)

    app = web.Application()

    webhook_requests_handler = SimpleRequestHandler(
        dispatcher=dp,
        bot=bot
    )

    webhook_requests_handler.register(app, path=WEBHOOK_PATH)
    setup_application(app, dp, bot=bot)
    web.run_app(app, host=WEB_SERVER_HOST, port=WEB_SERVER_PORT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Сейчас передо мной встала проблема - без понятия как это всё деплоить, до этого писал тг бота, но использовал поллинг и хостил на Railway, сейчас же у меня там закончилась подписка и не могу купить т. к. не принимает русские карты, хотя вроде как разобрался с конкретно этим сервисом. Помимо этого опыта не имею. Опробовал много различных сервисов, но никак не получается запустить бота.